# Total amount tax for a product

Tags: magento

Is there a way to show the tax amount for a product. I want to show the tax amount on the product page.

For example: 
The price is € 119 Euro and the the taxrate is 19%. Then a want to show the tax amount € 19 euro.

Hopefully someone can help me with this.

Gr,
Lex

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible but before you can do that you need to know the user shipping and billing data as tax calculations are based either on billing or shipping (country, region, zip) information and can be different for different locations